# How to speed up Gitlab CI job with cache and artifacts

Tags: rust, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wish Gitlab test job for my project on Rust run faster.
Locally it rebuilds pretty fast, but in gitlab job, avery build runs slow as a first one.
Looking for a way to use artifacts or cache from previous pipline to speed up rust test and build processe.

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  image: rust:latest
  script:
    - cargo test
```

Answer (score 9):

Gitlab CI/CD supports [caching between CI jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) using the `cache` key in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. It is only able to cache files in the project directory so you need to use the environment variable `CARGO_HOME`  if you also want to cache the cargo registry.

You can add a `cache` setting at the top level to setup a cache for all jobs that don't have a `cache` setting themselves and you can add it below a job definition to setup a cache configuration for this kind of job.

See the [keyword reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cache) for all possible configuration options.

Here is one example configuration that caches the cargo registry and the temporary build files and configures the `clippy` job to only use the cache but not write to it:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

cache: &global_cache          # Default cache configuration with YAML variable
                              # `global_cache` pointing to this block

  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}  # Share cache between all jobs on one branch/tag

  paths:                      # Paths to cache
    - .cargo/bin
    - .cargo/registry/index
    - .cargo/registry/cache
    - target/debug/deps
    - target/debug/build
  policy: pull-push           # All jobs not setup otherwise pull from
                              # and push to the cache

variables:
  CARGO_HOME: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.cargo # Move cargo data into the project
                                       # directory so it can be cached

# ...


test:
  stage: test
  image: rust:latest
  script:
    - cargo test


# only for demonstration, you can remove this block if not needed
clippy:
  stage: test
  image: rust:latest
  script:
    - cargo clippy # ...
  only:
    - master
  needs: []
  cache:
    <<: *global_cache  # Inherit the cache configuration `&global_cache` 
    policy: pull       # But only pull from the cache, don't push changes to it
```

If you want to use `cargo publish` from CI, you should then add `.cargo` to your `.gitignore` file. Otherwise `cargo publish` will show an error that there is an uncommitted directory `.cargo` in your project directory.